# Boyd & Chua 1985: Is the proof of Lemma 2 correct?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$I'm reading [this article by Boyd and Chua [1]](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/fading_volterra.pdf), in which they prove the approximability of arbitrary time-invariant (TI) operators (or filters) with polynomials of some basis filters with separation and *fading memory* (FM) properties. This shows that those operators, indeed have fintie Volterra expansion approximates.

Consider the following:

- $C(\Bbb R)$ as the space of bounded continuous functions $u: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$,
- $\norm u = \sup_{t \in \Bbb R} |u(t)|$ being their norm,
- $\Bbb R_-$ as $\{t : t \le 0 \}$, with analogous definitions for $C(\Bbb R_-)$ and $\norm\cdot$ as above,
- and time-invariant functionals $F: C(\Bbb R_-) \to \Bbb R$ and time-invariant operators $N: C(\Bbb R) \to C(\Bbb R)$.

- $K=\bigl\{u\in C(\Bbb R): \abs{u(t)}\le M_1\land\abs{u(s)-u(t)}\le M_2(s-t)\;\forall t, s\in\Bbb R, t<s\bigr\}$: explicitly, $K$ is the space of bounded uniformly Lipschitz continuous functions. Functions belonging to $K$ are called *signals*.

- $K_-=\{u\in K : u(t)=0\text{ if }t>0\}$: Boyd & Chua prefer to define $K_-$ by using a "projection" operator $P$ such that
  $$\DeclareMathOperator{\dmu}{d\!}
  Pu(t) =
  \begin{cases}
  u(t) & t\le 0\\
  0 & t>0
  \end{cases}
  $$ and then noting that $K_- =P K$. Be it noted that $K_-$ is compact in $C(\Bbb R)$ but only with respect to the weighted $\sup$ norm
  defined as
  $$
  \norm u_w=\sup_{t\le 1} \abs{u(t)w(-t)}
  $$
  where $w:\Bbb R_+\to(0,1]$ is a weight function such that $\lim_{t\to\infty} w(t)=0$ (see below).
- For every TI operator $N$, an associated $F$ is defined by $Fu=Nu_e(0)$, in which $u_e$ is some extension of $u$ from $C(\Bbb R_-)$ to $C(\Bbb R)$.
- Furthermore, the fading memory (FM) property is defined for TI operators on $N \in K \subset C(\Bbb R)$ as the existence of some weight function $w: \Bbb R_+ \to (0,1]$ with $\lim_{t \to \infty} w(t) = 0$ that makes $K_-$ closed w.r.t. the weighted norm $w$. i.e. for any $v,u \in K$, one can find a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$ such that

$$\norm{u-v}_w:= \sup_{t\le 0} \abs{u(t)-v(t)}w(-t) < \delta \implies \abs{Nu(0) - Nv(0)} < \epsilon$$

*Lemma 2* states that there are some functionals on $K_-$ that separate points. To prove this, a class of functionals $G \in \mathbf G \subset K_-$ is defined by
$$\mathbf{G}=\left\{G(u)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}g(\tau)u(-\tau)\dmu\tau :u\in K_-\land\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\abs{g(\tau)}w(\tau)^{-1}\dmu\tau\right\}$$
which are (shown to be) continuous w.r.t. the weighted norm $w$ (thanks to the condition introduced above). The authors further construct functions $g_0$ defined by:

$$g_0(t):= [u(-t)-v(-t)] w(t)\exp (-t)$$

and their associated $G_0$ **assuming** that they belong to $\mathbf G$. Then, they show that $g_0$ indeed separates points on $K_-$. However, **I don't understand why $G_0 \in \mathbf G$ in the first place.** $g_0$, by construction, dependends on $u$ and $v$. Thus, it does not look to me that $G_0$ is even time-invariant (simply shifting $u$ and $v$ in time will yield a different $g_0$). So my question is why is the proof of this lemma correct?

**Reference**

[1] Stephen Boyd, Leon O. Chua, "[Fading memory and the problem of approximating nonlinear operators with Volterra series](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/fading_volterra.pdf)" (English), IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems 32, 1150-1161 (1985), [MR0809696](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0809696), [Zbl 0587.93028](https://zbmath.org/0587.93028), doi:[10.1109/TCS.1985.1085649](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCS.1985.1085649).

Comment: You should explain what you mean by (i) "a functional $G_0 \in \mathbf{G}$, by defined an associated function $g_0$" ("defined" in what way exactly? "associated" in what way exactly? "by defined" or "defined by"? 
(ii) "endowed with a decaying weight $w(t)$ to ensure its compactness" ("endowed" in what way exactly? "ensure" how?) (iii) "w.r.t. $w(t)$ on $K_-$". 
Also, (i) undefined, non-mathematical terms such as "inputs" and "past times" should be avoided or, at least, defined mathematically; (ii) the functions are $u$ and $v$, not $u(t)$ and $v(t)$, please.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for your comment. Please note that I used their own wording precisely. Yet, I'm sure they would agree with you on the word choice: they addressed this issue in section IX, starting with "It is possible to generalize the results of this paper to a clean and simple mathematical form, at the cost of some engineering intuition". Indeed, they avoid confusion by setting up a context for every single term they used. I skipped explaining it, assuming that it is clear enough. But if not, I'll update my question.

Comment: My comment was mainly, not on the word choice, but on having everything defined -- defined in your post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'll try to improve further the question of arash. Partly of the responsibility of the above mess is mine. ;)

Comment: @DanieleTampieri : Thank you for your comment and your generosity.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Many thanks for your kind comment. I decided to rewrite my question after Iosif's comments. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Arash, I am going to post an answer soon: I'll edit also the question, if you don't mind, as already I were preparing a revision.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/437909/4), TeX note: although I think they are usually typeset identically, if it is to be written symbolically, then it is semantically better to use `\land` for conjunction rather than `\wedge`.  While fixing some typos, I edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @LSpice, your suggestions pertaining TeX are always very useful to me.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you very much. Truly appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't let the bad wording of the paper fool you. The statement of lemma 2 in [1] above does not mean that the functional $G$ constructed by the kernel $g_0$ separates all the points $u, v\in K_-$ such that $u\neq v$: *it means only that, for any such two functions, you can construct a kernel such that the associated linear functional constructed as above is such that $Gu\neq Gv$*. At first I was fooled by the same thought but then I read *Remark 4* in the same page ([1], §IV p. 1153), which contains the statement quoted below

> Suppose $E$ is a compact metric space and $\mathbf G$ a set of continuous functionals on $E$ which separate points, that is, for any distinct $u,v\in E$ there is a $G\in\mathbf G$ such that $Gu \neq Gv$.

Then I simply realized that the authors want only to show that the functional
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dmu}{d\!}G_0(q)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}g_0(\tau)q(-\tau)\dmu\tau \quad \forall q\in K_-
$$
with the kernel $g_0$ constructed as described above is such that $G_0 u\neq G_0v$ for **any fixed couple of different functions chosen for its construction**. If $u_1, v_1\in K_-$ are a different couple such that $u_1\neq v_1$, you do not know if $G_0u_1\neq G_0 v_1$ (an in general this is not true): however you can construct another functional, say $G_1$, whose kernel is defined as exactly as $g_0$ i.e.
$$
g_1(t):= [u_1(-t)-v_1(-t)] w(t)\exp (-t)
$$
and separates the new points but obviously possibly not the points $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I apologize for perhaps having "mugged" you an answer but, as you see, this is only a bad wording problem in the text, with no analytical difficulty involved.

Comment: No need whatsoever for you to apologize for anything.

Comment: I'm convinced by this answer. Yet, if that's what this Lemma wanted to say, it seems to me that the main premise of the paper (existence of $u$-independent Volterra expansionis for TI operators) not met. I may be wrong. I'll think about it and post an update or another question. Nonetheless, thanks to all who engaged.